# nginx container can't find cert files on host

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I'm trying to rebuild a reverse proxy but I keep getting these errors that it can't find the cert. These are the same confs I set up the previous server with. Everything seems fine with them... any ideas?

Docker logs:

```
nginx: [emerg] cannot load  certificate "/opt/nginx/certs/cert.crt": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL:  error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or  directory:fopen('/opt/nginx/certs/cert.crt','r') error:2006D080:BIO  routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)
2020/12/02  20:43:56 [emerg] 1#1: cannot load certificate  "/opt/nginx/certs/cert.crt": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL:  error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or  directory:fopen('/opt/nginx/certs/cert.crt','r') error:2006D080:BIO  routines:BIO_new_file:no such file
```

Files are in `/opt/nginx`:

```
j@netconf:/opt/nginx/certs$ pwd; ll
/opt/nginx/certs
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Dec  2 19:30 ./
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Dec  2 20:09 ../ 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 7064 Dec  2 19:30 cert.crt 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1704 Nov 16 21:56 key.pem
```

I'm mapping this directory to my container:

```yaml
    version: '3.3'
    services:
        nginx:
            image: nginx:stable-alpine
            volumes:
                - /opt/nginx/web.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
                - /opt/nginx/certs/:/opt/nginx/certs/
            network_mode: host
            ipc: host
            restart: unless-stopped     # or "always"
            command: /bin/sh -c "nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
```

nginx `conf`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name netdisco.domain;
    return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name netdisco.domain;
    ssl_certificate /opt/nginx/certs/cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /opt/nginx/certs/key.pem;

    sendfile on;

    charset utf-8;
    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 50G; # adjust to taste

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://10.100.0.30:5000/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

Comment: Everything seems fine. Only I'd like to point that you don't need to put a trailing slash when mounting a directory. Try changing `/opt/nginx/certs/:/opt/nginx/certs/` to this `/opt/nginx/certs:/opt/nginx/certs`.

Comment: Yeah, I think I just copied the path from a tab-complete in terminal there.    Shouldn't matter, but I removed it anyway and ran compose again; still the same issue.

Comment: Then you have to dive in and see how it looks from the inside. Run `docker-compose run nginx ash` and examine the files. Try reading them.

Comment: Could be permissions issue. the owner of the files is root but nginx is running as non root user ?
Try to get into the container and check it from inside as per @anemyte said above